# Change calculator

Tags: c++, c++11

I likes my use of functions so I'm mostly looking for little things but if you see something tell me :)

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


void addQuarter(double &num); void addDime(double &num); void 
addNikle(double &num); void addPennie(double &num);
bool quarterValid(double num, const double finalNum); bool dimeValid(double num, const double finalNum); bool nikleValid(double num, const double finalNum); bool pennieValid(double num, const double finalNum);

class change {
public:
    change() = default;
    change(double a) { setChange(a); }
    void getChange();
    void setChange(double change) { totalAmmount = change; }
    int getQuaters() const { return ammountQuarters; }
    int getDimes() const { return ammountDimes; }
    int getNikles() const { return ammountNikles; }
    int getPennies() const { return ammountPennies; }
private:
    double totalAmmount; double ammountSoFar = 0;
    int ammountQuarters = 0, ammountDimes = 0, ammountNikles = 0, ammountPennies = 0;
};

void change::getChange() {
    while (quarterValid(ammountSoFar, totalAmmount)) {
         addQuarter(ammountSoFar);
         ++ammountQuarters;
    }
    while (dimeValid(ammountSoFar, totalAmmount)) {
         addDime(ammountSoFar);
         ++ammountDimes;
    }
    while (nikleValid(ammountSoFar, totalAmmount)) {
        addNikle(ammountSoFar);
        ++ammountNikles;
    }
    while (pennieValid(ammountSoFar, totalAmmount)) {
        addPennie(ammountSoFar);
        ++ammountPennies;
    }
}

void addQuarter(double &num) {
    num += .25;

void addDime(double &num) {
    num += .10;
}
void addNikle(double &num) {
    num += .05;
}
void addPennie(double &num) {
    num += .01;
}

bool quarterValid(double num, const double finalNum) {
    if ((num + .25) <= finalNum)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool dimeValid(double num, const double finalNum) {
    if ((num + .10) <= finalNum)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool nikleValid(double num, const double finalNum) {
    if ((num + .05) <= finalNum)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool pennieValid(double num, const double finalNum) {
    if ((num + .01) <= finalNum)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't use double for monetary values. Use integer types just make it multiples of the smallest denomination (ie in US use cents).

Answer (score 11):

#### Class vs function

The problem you're solving is basically: given $X, make change. That sounds like a function to me:

```
??? makeChange(double amount);
```

As in - you're returning something that tells the user how many quarters, pennies, etc, are needed. But if you make `change` a class like this, it's solving two problems - both the making change problem *and* the determining the solution. That's mixing responsibilities. At least, you should make `makeChange` static - certainly there's no reason for `change` to hold onto `totalAmmount`, nor for it to be default-constructible.

But really, what makes the most sense is to have a normal POD:

```
struct change {
    int quarters;
    int dimes;
    int nickels;
    int pennies;
};
```

And just return that.

#### using namespace std;

[Don't do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/2069064) Especially in a header. *Especially* when you're not even using anything from `std`. You don't need the `<iostream>` import either.

#### Use of functions

This is too many functions. First of all, if you're going to declare your functions up front and define them later, **one function per line**. But secondly, do you really need separate functions for each coin? They all do the same thing - the only difference is the amount. So just make that another argument:

```
int makeChangeWith(double& amount, double coin)
{
    int num = 0;
    while (amount >= coin) {
        amount -= coin;
        ++num;
    }
    return num;
}
```

And then your `getChange()` becomes:

```
change makeChange(double amount) {
    change result;

    result.quarters = makeChangeWith(amount, 0.25);
    result.dimes = makeChangeWith(amount, 0.10);
    result.nickels = makeChangeWith(amount, 0.05);
    result.pennies = makeChangeWith(amount, 0.01);

    return result;
}
```

Moreover, once we do it this way, we don't have to subtract one at a time. We can just divide. If we have $5.01, I don't need to subtract off 20 quarters, I can see that `(int)(5.01 / .25)` is 20 and go from there.

#### Floating point math

Floating point math is annoying and imprecise. It'd be better to avoid it entirely. Convert your values to an integral number of cents up front:

```
int cents = amount * 100;
```

And then decrease/divide by 25, 10, 5, and 1 instead.

#### Spelling

The coins are a nickel and a penny, not nikle and pennie.